# nicescroll not working after bootstrap modal close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nicescroll version 3.6.6 and Bootstrap 3.3.6.

- When I click the link I have to pass some parameter in `url` and according to that I have to show the modal, **but** when the modal appears my window shows the regular Bootstrap scrollbar.
- After closing the modal nicescroll is not working. As in the page is not scrolling. My code for nicescroll is:

  ```
  $('html').niceScroll({
      cursorcolor: "#233243",
      cursorborder: "0px solid #fff",
      railpadding: {
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0
      },
      cursorwidth: "5px",
      cursorborderradius: "0px",
      cursoropacitymin: 0,
      cursoropacitymax: 0.7,
      boxzoom: true,
      horizrailenabled: false,
      zindex: 9999,

  });
  ```

#### My link is

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>&oid=<?php echo $v1['outlet_id'] ?>&offid=<?php echo $v1['offer_id'] ?> " >
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what the actual link looks like on the front-end?

Comment: Try adding the modal markup to the top level (ie, its parent tag should be the <html> tag.